# Getting element the event is attached to

Tags: javascript

I have a nested html structure that needs to change in a certain way when clicked. For that, i need the element that the event is bound to, not the element that is clicked

For example....

```
theDesiredElement.addEventListener('click', 
    function() {
         ... i need 'theDesiredElement' here
    }
, false);
```

Getting event.target get's the clicked element, not the element that the event is bound to. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you explain what higher level problem you're really trying to solve?  If the event is not propagating, then `this` or `event.target` will be the element that the event occurred in and the event handler is attached to.

Comment: The element that the event is bound to and the element click isn't the same?

Comment: Use `this` http://jsfiddle.net/zLLyS/

Comment: Yea, i just found that out 15 seconds after i posted the question. I found it on the MDN. Kill me and hide my grave.

Comment: @MarioLegenda congrats on finding the answer to your question on MDN, don't forget to select an answer to the question if any of the answers below match the solution you came up with. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
theDesiredElement.addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
         ... i need 'theDesiredElement' here
         theDesiredElement=event.target;
    }
, false);
```

Based on what you are looking, you may have to get the parent node of target;

Answer (score 0):

The function that you pass in, as the bound function for processing the click event, should take the `event` triggered as a parameter to it, allowing you to get details like the target of the event.

E.g.

```
var el = document.getElementById("theDesiredElement");
el.addEventListener('click', function(/*DOMEvent*/ evt) {
    ...
}, false);
```

Hanging off of `evt` you should be able to find the element that was clicked--e.g. *theDesiredElement*, accessing it with:

```
var desired = evt.target;
```

See the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbZgW/

For more details about `addEventListener`, take a look at [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using this inside the function bound to the event. It points to the desired element.

Comment: Or you could also use a closure and `theDesiredElement` inside of it.

Comment: when i used that, the element was undefined. using this is just fine but i have a hunch that browser support is not wide on that. I'll do some research on it.